# Rails 4: can't update polymorphic object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

My object **`Item`** has polymorphic association as **`element`** (It can be a video, texte etc.)

When I want to update the  **`Item`** (and his **`element`**) I do this :

```
@item.update_attributes(param_update_item)
```

I call this :

```
def param_update_item

  params.permit(:name, :visible, :title, element: [:content, :url, :html])

  # params.permit(:name, :visible, :title) # - don't get error, but obviously don't ubdate the element

end
```

the permitted params is good, but when the `update_attributes` is called, I get an error :

```
 undefined method `primary_key' for ActionController::Parameters:Class
```

Any idea?

EDIT :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true, dependent: :destroy
end

module Element
  included do
    has_one :item, :as => :element, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

and an exemple of model (in my example)

```
class Texte < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Element

  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

My Item in DB :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base {
          :id => :integer,
          :element_id => :integer,
          :element_type => :string,
 ....  }
```

and when I do `item.element`    I get :

```
 => <Texte id: 15757, content: "RE3  3232 /...", created_at: ...>
```

Comment: Can I see the relationships in the models for item and element so I can get a better knowledge on how the relationships are set up?

Comment: @aaron.v you can see my edit

Comment: Your error message suggests that you don't have a primary key for the table 'parameters'.  Can you confirm that that table has a primary key (id integer not null primary key)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your element with your item, you should tell the model that your item should accept nested attributes for element.

```
module Element
  included do
    has_one :item, :as => :element, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :element 
  end
end
```

But I think you might have your relationships set up incorrectly. You say that you want your element to be polymorphic, but your item only belongs to element.

I would do

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element
end
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item
  belongs_to :elementable, polymorphic: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
module Elementable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :element, as: :elementable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :element
  end
end
class Texte < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elementable
end
```

Then in your item update, you can permit

```
element_attributes: [# all your element attributes in here]
```

This would require you to change the item table to have element_id and add elements table in a migration

```
create_table :elements do |t|
  t.belongs_to :elementable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This would create columns named elementable_type and elementable_id

I would read this for more info [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: Before change all the structure, I've put in an Edit how my Item/element works, to see is theres is a simple modification to do

Comment: My question is, if we structure this way, is there a need for item anymore? Or can we drive everything through element? It doesn't make sense to have an element that has an item and your Texte or Video or other objects to have an element, a has_one with a has_one. Can element take over Item's role or vice versa? Item could be set up a similar way, with itemable_type and itemable_id

Comment: I see what you mean, unfortunately I can't really change the structure, everything is in production since 2 years with 2 application using the same DB. I'm forced to keep the structure as this